Tamil Letters not displayed Correctly in TCPDF
My PHP Code is below describes. i want to display tamil letters in pdf using php..
**My Code Is **
<?php
    require_once('tcpdf_include.php');
    $pdf = new TCPDF('P', 'mm', 'A4', true, 'UTF-8', false);
    $pdf->AddPage();
    $pdf->SetFont('notosanstamil', '', 12); // 'notosanstamil' is the font name
    $pdf->Write(0, 'கோவில்', '', 0, 'L', true, 0, false, false, 0);
    $pdf->Output('example.pdf', 'I');
?>

``
But Output is
'

notosanstamil is not default font, so you must supply font source
